# Using Intersection between two lists inside where statement of Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, abp

I have a parent table named `Employees` which has a foreign key in a child table `EmployeePrisons` as follows

```
    public class EmployeePrisons : FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public long PrisonId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public PrisonsLkpt Prison { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want the user to be able to select more than one `prisons`, to find all the `employees` that work in that list of `prisonsId`s. So i was thinking of using intersect inside the where clause. like this
The variable `prisons` is also list

```
              employees=employees.Where(x => x.Prisons.Select(c => c.PrisonId).ToList().Intersect(prisons).Count()!=0 &&  x.Attendance.Any(y => y.ExitTime == null));
```

But it always give this error:

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int64]' of method
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int64] Intersect[Int64](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int64],
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int64])' (Parameter
> 'arg0')

Please if anyone can help me it will be very useful

Comment: Please use the right tag. It's either EF6 or EF core (+ a version).

Comment: Please read the message. You are trying to intersect PrisonIds with Prisons. Also you don't need intesect and count check for != 0. Simply use Any().

Comment: `employees.Where(x => x.Prisons.Any(c => prisons.Contains(c.PrisonId)) && x.Attendance.Any(y => y.ExitTime == null))`?

Comment: @CetinBasoz: The message doesn't say they're trying to intersect PrisonIds with Prisons. It says they're trying to use a `List<long>` where they need an `IQueryable<long>`. It seems removing the call to `.ToList()` might be enough to fix this error. But the query can certainly be simplifies in other ways.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, please reread the query and the message. I don't care if Id is int or long. What matters is they are not the same type. They are not both long for example.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I've reread them several times. The OP doesn't mention the type of the `prisons` variable, and the error only references `List<Int64>`, `IQueryable<Int64>`, and `IEnumerable<Int64>`. There's nothing about any other type in that error message.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior,  he doesn't, message does.

Comment: Could you post other entities? I know how to do such query, but I need more information.